# How to generate a distributable library jar only with public functions and members?

Tags: java, android, jar, obfuscation, proguard

I have recently been exploring various jars with [JD-GUI](http://jd.benow.ca/) in order to figure out how to correctly hide away private code in a distributable Android library jar. I noticed that some jars, such as NewRelic's Android API, contain only public functions and members and no code within them. For example, here's what the jar looks like when opened via JD-GUI:

[image: NewRelicJarJDGUI]

Notice that no code is presented inside each of the functions. I opened the jar via [Zipeg](http://www.zipeg.com/) and saw that the compiled .class files are nicely laid out within the jar:

[image: NewRelicJarZipeg]

I am attempting to achieve the same result in my quest to create a distributable Android library jar. So far, I have used ProGuard to mask away code, but this has not provided the result I was looking for. Here is what the content of the jar ended up looking like:

[image: MyJarZipeg]

Note that there are a bunch of .class files per class. Worse, when inspected via JD-GUI, the code looked like the following:

[image: MyJarJDGUI]

What kind of a tool can I use to obfuscate/mask away my code similar to NewRelic's jar? I want to display only the headers of public functions. Everything that is not public should be hidden away. I am currently using Android Studio, building via Gradle, and running ProGuard manually on the jar that is output somewhere underneath the build directory of the project.

Here is the ProGuard configuration file I am using:

```
-injars build/libs/SDK.jar
-outjars build/libs/SDK_pro.jar

-libraryjars '/Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/platforms/android-19/android.jar'

-printmapping build/libs/mapping.txt
-verbose
-dontoptimize
-dontpreverify
-dontshrink
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-keepparameternames
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,
                SourceFile,LineNumberTable,*Annotation*,EnclosingMethod

-keep public class * {
    public protected *;
}

-keepclassmembernames class * {
    java.lang.Class class$(java.lang.String);
    java.lang.Class class$(java.lang.String, boolean);
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID;
    private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
    java.lang.Object readResolve();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot see any code in the NewRelic Api jar, it's simply because there **no code** in this jar. Quoting the documentation (from https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/java/java-agent-api, emphasis mine)

> There is no problem if you call the API when the Java Agent is not running. **The API methods are just stubs; the implementation is added when the Java agent loads the class**.

If you look at newrelic agent jar, you'll find the same kind of obfuscated code that you see with your own jar.

There no way to really hide your code, the best you can do is to obfuscate it (and proguard is a good choice). And if you really care about the content of the interface jar, you can separate your code in two jar, one for the API one for the implementation, but the code has to be somewhere.

Comment: Are you saying that they use class loaders to load the code from another location, such as the internet? Shouldn't the code for the loading logic be present somewhere in the jar? It doesn't seem to be there.

Comment: no, I think the implementation is dynamically added by the agent ; an application using newrelic will include both the api (which contains only stubs) and the agent jar (which contains the actual code). The loading mechanism does not need to be in the api jar as long as you also have the agent jar in the classpath.